# C# How do I get the other variables to cooperate with the char array so I can use char to find number of times letters appeared

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, dictionary, char

So, I have bolded what I think I should change. The inserted char is my edition. I have created this program seamlessly with string and now I am to change the program from counting the number of occurrences of words to the number of letter occurrences.

I know in order to do that I needed to change the array to char so that it is a character array. However when I do that, i can  no longer compare it and if I try to change wordkey to var it still doesn't let me compare it.

The book I am reading says that if I wanted to compare the characters I could just have method `DisplayDictionary` receive an argument of type `SortedDictionary<char, int>` without modification. If I could just get a nudge in the right direction. I  have been tinkering with this for a couple days now and just can't seem to figure it out.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
 ***{
        //create sorted dictionary based on user input
        SortedDictionary<char, int> dictionary = CollectWords();***

       //display sorted dictionary content
       DisplayDictionary(dictionary);
    } // end main

***//created sorted dictionary from user input

private static SortedDictionary<char, int> CollectWords()
{***

    //create a new sorted dictionary
     SortedDictionary<string, int> dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();


    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    //split input text into tokens
    string[] words = Regex.Split(input, @"\s");

    //processing input words
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        string wordKey = word.ToLower();

        //if ghe dictionary contains the word
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(wordKey))
        {
            ++dictionary[wordKey];
        }//end if
        else
            //add new word with count 1 to tge dictionary
            dictionary.Add(wordKey, 1);
    }//end foreach method

    ***return dictionary;***
}//end sorted dictionary wordKey

***//display dictionary content
private static void DisplayDictionary<K, V>(SortedDictionary<K, V> dictionary)
    {***
    Console.WriteLine("\nSorted dictionary contains:\n{0, -12}{1, -12} ", "Key: ", "Value: ");

    //generate output for each key in the sorted dictionary
    //by iterating though the Keys property with a foreach statement
    foreach (K key in dictionary.Keys)
        Console.WriteLine("{0, -12}{1, -12} ", key, dictionary[key]);

        Console.WriteLine("\nsize: {0}", dictionary.Count);

    }//end display method
}//end class
```

Comment: Your dictionary key is of type `char`, but `wordKey` is a `string`. So `dictionary.ContainsKey(wordKey)` will never work. -- *Maybe* you want another inner loop like `foreach (var character in wordKey) { [...] }` and then check if `dictionary.ContainsKey(character)`?

Comment: Also, you have looots of comments... if someone told you to "comment every line": stop it (if you can and it's not mandatory for homework or the like)! Comments like `//end if` are useless. If you're using a decent IDE (like Visual Studio) it should highlight which closing brace belongs to which opening one. If you code is so long, that both don't fit on one screen: you're doing it wrong! Refactor into smaller methods. And you shouldn't need `//end class`, because you only have *one* class per file anyway, right?

Comment: In general, write **code** so that you understand, **what** it does without the need for comments. And *only* use comments (if it is not immediately obvious) to describe **why** something is done the way it is.

Comment: Ok. My instructors have told us to use comments so that if another developer were to debug a program, they would be able to know exactly what is going on. I may have taken it to the extreme.

Answer (score 0):

The `String` class implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so you can do just this:

```
var dictionary = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();
foreach(var ch in input)
{
    if(dictionary.ContainsKey(ch))
        dictionary[ch]++;
    else
        dictionary[ch] = 1;
}
```

If you still want to reuse your generated words collection, you can convert it to a chars collection with this:

```
var chars = words.SelectMany(w => w); //then foreach(var ch in chars)...
```

Or if you want to use the magic of LINQ, you can even reduce everything to a one-liner:

```
var dictionary = input.GroupBy(ch => ch).ToDictionary(ch => ch.Key, ch => ch.Count());
```

Note however that in this case you get a regular dictionary, not a `SortedDictionary`.

Comment: I like the way you wrote the dictionary[i]++, we have always done it differently.. I guess I exopected that if I wrote  'SortedDictionary<char, int> dictionary = new SortedDictionary<char int>();' it would work.